# How can I prove that this sequence converges to 0?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

Let $x_n$ be a sequence for which there are two numbers $p$ and $m$ ($p\in]0;1[$ and $ m \in N$) such that for every $n\geq m$ it holds that $\vert x_{n+1}\vert$ $\leq $$p$$\vert x_{n}\vert$
Find the convergence of $x_n$

So I have this solution which I´m not quite sure it's correct

I started saying that because $p\in]0;1[$ we can say that for every $n\geq m$

$$\vert x_{n+1}\vert\leq p\vert x_{n}\vert\lt\vert x_n \vert$$

so this means that $\vert x_n \vert $ is strictly decreasing for $n\geq m$

Also we notice that:
$$\vert x_{m+1}\vert\leq p\vert x_{m}\vert$$

$$\vert x_{m+2}\vert\leq p\vert x_{m+1}\vert\leq p^2\vert x_m \vert$$
$$\vert x_{m+3}\vert\leq p\vert x_{m+2}\vert\leq p^3\vert x_m \vert$$

we can prove by induction that for any $ k \in N$ it holds:

$$\vert x_{m+k}\vert\leq p^k\vert x_m \vert$$

Now we can prove that $x_n$ converge to $0$

In order to do that we have to prove that for any $\epsilon \gt 0$ we can find some $ M \in N$ such that

$$n\gt M \to \vert x_n \vert \lt \epsilon$$

and we can do this by choosing

$$M=m+ \log_{p} {\frac{\epsilon}{\vert x_m \vert}}$$

Notice that for small values of $\epsilon $ this logarithm is positive so:

$$n \gt M \to n\gt m+ \log_{p} {\frac{\epsilon}{\vert x_m \vert}} \gt m$$

and because $ \vert x_n \vert $ is strictly decreasing for $n\geq m$

$$ \vert x_{n} \vert\lt \vert x_{m+ \log_{p} {\frac{\epsilon}{\vert x_m \vert}}} \vert$$

and because of $(1)$

$$\vert x_{m+ \log_{p} {\frac{\epsilon}{\vert x_m \vert}}} \vert \leq p^{log_{p} {\frac{\epsilon}{\vert x_m \vert}}} \vert x_m \vert =\epsilon $$

By transitivity we get:

$$ \vert x_{n} \vert\lt \epsilon $$

Which completes our proof.

So Im not sure about the part in which I claim that the logarithm is positive for small values of n and algo I was wondering if maybe I can just prove it using the ratio test but I'm not quite sure how to use it correctly. Also I used (1) with k being a logarith which is not a natural number so, how could I fix this? Maybe by using the floor function or something like that
Id appreciate some help

Comment: Simpler: You proved that $|x_{m+k}|<p^k|x_m|$ so, $|x_n|<p^n|x_0|$. Now, because $p\in(0,1)$, $p^n\to0$ and $x_0$ is a positive constant, so $p^n|x_0|\to0$ and you're done.

Comment: Putting $x_{n+1}=f(x_n)$, the first inequality says that $f$ is contractant, and then the convergence of this sequence is assured.

Comment: Thanks Tito Eliatron...I just have one question, wouldn't the inequality that you say hold for only n greater than or equal to m?